# Formatting XML strings in JavaScript for readability

Tags: javascript, regex, formatting

I've created a vanilla JS function to indent XML strings so they can be more easily read. It uses some pretty nasty regex...yes, I know it's a cardinal sin for XML/HTML, but it works. For instance, this string...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><ns:getCourseResponse xmlns:ns="http://course.ws.blackboard" xmlns:ax212="http://course.ws.blackboard/xsd" xmlns:ax211="http://ws.platform.blackboard/xsd" /></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

...would look like this after being passed through the function:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:getCourseResponse xmlns:ns="http://course.ws.blackboard" xmlns:ax212="http://course.ws.blackboard/xsd" xmlns:ax211="http://ws.platform.blackboard/xsd" />
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here's the function itself. What can I do to simplify it?

```
function formatXML(input) {

    // PART 1: Add \n where necessary
    // A) add \n between sets of angled brackets without content between them
    // B) remove \n between opening and closing tags of the same node if no content is between them
    // C) add \n between a self-closing set of angled brackets and the next set
    // D) split it into an array

    xmlString = input.trim()
        .replace(/>\s*</g,'>\n<')                   
        .replace(/(<[^\/>].*>)\n(<[\/])/g,'$1$2')      
        .replace(/(<\/[^>]+>|<[^>]+\/>)(<[^>]+>)/g,'$1\n$2');            
    xmlArr = xmlString.split('\n');

    // PART 2: indent each line appropriately

    var tabs = '';          //store the current indentation
    var start = 0;          //starting line
    if (/^<[?]xml/.test(xmlArr[0])) start++;    //if the first line is a header, ignore it

    for (var i = start; i < xmlArr.length; i++) { //for each line
        var line = xmlArr[i].trim();    //trim it just in case
        if (/^<[/]/.test(line)) { // if the line is a closing tag                
            // remove one tab from the store
            // add the tabs at the beginning of the line
            tabs = tabs.replace(/.$/, '');
            xmlArr[i] = tabs + line;            
        } else if (/<.*>.*<\/.*>|<.*[^>]\/>/.test(line)) { // if the line contains an entire node                
            // leave the store as is
            // add the tabs at the beginning of the line
            xmlArr[i] = tabs + line;
        } else { // if the line starts with an opening tag and does not contain an entire node                
            // add the tabs at the beginning of the line
            // and add one tab to the store
            xmlArr[i] = tabs + line;            
            tabs += '\t';
        }                    
    }

    //rejoin the array to a string and return it
    return xmlArr.join('\n');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking something like this, nice idea. But Your function couldn't parse text nodes. Try insert some text, example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body>textNode<soapenv:temp>innerText</soapenv:temp><ns:temp><ns:getCourseResponse xmlns:ns="http://course.ws.blackboard" /></ns:temp></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

My proposition for this problem is:

1) change spliting code in this way:

```
.replace( /(<([a-zA-Z]+\b)[^>]*>)(?!<\/\2>|[\w\s])/g, "$1\n" ) //add \n after tag if not followed by the closing tag of pair or text node
.replace( /(<\/[a-zA-Z]+[^>]*>)/g, "$1\n") //add \n after closing tag
.replace( />\s+(.+?)\s+<(?!\/)/g, ">\n$1\n<") //add \n between sets of angled brackets and text node between them
.replace( />(.+?)<([a-zA-Z])/g, ">\n$1\n<$2") //add \n between angled brackets and text node between them
.replace(/\?></, "?>\n<") //detect a header of XML
```

2) little modify third statement `else if` and add one more:

```
 else if (/<.*>/.test(line)) //if the line starts with an opening tag and does not contain an entire node
 {
  xmlArr[i] = tabs + line;  //add the tabs at the beginning of the line
  tabs += indent;  //and add one indent to the store
 }
 else  //if the line contain a text node
 {
  xmlArr[i] = tabs + line;  // add the tabs at the beginning of the line
 }
```

So finaly, our function will be:

```
function formatXML(input,indent)
{
  indent = indent || '\t'; //you can set/define other ident than tabs


  //PART 1: Add \n where necessary
  xmlString = input.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');  //trim it (just in case) {method trim() not working in IE8}

  xmlString = input
                   .replace( /(<([a-zA-Z]+\b)[^>]*>)(?!<\/\2>|[\w\s])/g, "$1\n" ) //add \n after tag if not followed by the closing tag of pair or text node
                   .replace( /(<\/[a-zA-Z]+[^>]*>)/g, "$1\n") //add \n after closing tag
                   .replace( />\s+(.+?)\s+<(?!\/)/g, ">\n$1\n<") //add \n between sets of angled brackets and text node between them
                   .replace( />(.+?)<([a-zA-Z])/g, ">\n$1\n<$2") //add \n between angled brackets and text node between them
                   .replace(/\?></, "?>\n<") //detect a header of XML

  xmlArr = xmlString.split('\n');  //split it into an array (for analise each line separately)



  //PART 2: indent each line appropriately

  var tabs = '';  //store the current indentation
  var start = 0;  //starting line

  if (/^<[?]xml/.test(xmlArr[0]))  start++;  //if the first line is a header, ignore it

  for (var i = start; i < xmlArr.length; i++) //for each line
  {  
    var line = xmlArr[i].replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');  //trim it (just in case)

    if (/^<[/]/.test(line))  //if the line is a closing tag
     {
      tabs = tabs.replace(indent, '');  //remove one indent from the store
      xmlArr[i] = tabs + line;  //add the tabs at the beginning of the line
     }
     else if (/<.*>.*<\/.*>|<.*[^>]\/>/.test(line))  //if the line contains an entire node
     {
      //leave the store as is
      xmlArr[i] = tabs + line; //add the tabs at the beginning of the line
     }
     else if (/<.*>/.test(line)) //if the line starts with an opening tag and does not contain an entire node
     {
      xmlArr[i] = tabs + line;  //add the tabs at the beginning of the line
      tabs += indent;  //and add one indent to the store
     }
     else  //if the line contain a text node
     {
      xmlArr[i] = tabs + line;  // add the tabs at the beginning of the line
     }
  }


  //PART 3: return formatted string (source)
  return  xmlArr.join('\n');  //rejoin the array to a string and return it
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another concept is to read the string nodes by nodes and split it on the fly:

```
function XMLTree( xmlString , indent )
{
  indent = indent || "\t"; //can be specified by second argument of the function

  var tabs = "";  //store the current indentation

  var result = xmlString.replace(
    /\s*<.+?>|\s*[^<]+/g , //pattern to match nodes (angled brackets or text)
    function(m){ 
      m = m.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");  //trim the match

      if (/^<[?]xml/.test(m))  return m+"\n";  //if the match is a header, ignore it

      if (/^<[/]/.test(m))  //if the match is a closing tag
       {
        tabs = tabs.replace(indent, "");  //remove one indent from the store
        m = tabs + m;  //add the tabs at the beginning of the match
       }
       else if (/<.*[^>]\/>/.test(m))  //if the match contains an entire node
       {
        //leave the store as is
        m = tabs + m; //add the tabs at the beginning of the match
       }
       else if (/<.*>/.test(m)) //if the match starts with an opening tag and does not contain an entire node
       {
        m = tabs + m;  //add the tabs at the beginning of the matche
        tabs += indent;  //and add one indent to the store
       }
       else  //if the match contain a text node
       {
        m = tabs + m;  // add the tabs at the beginning of the match
       }

      //return m+"\n";
      return "\n"+m; //content has additional space(line) from header
    }
  );

  //Additional fixes
//result = result.replace(/(<[^\/>]*>)\n\s*(<[\/])/g, "$1$2");  //remove \n between opening and closing tags of the same node if no content is between them
  result = result.replace(/(<[^\/>]*)>\n\s*(<[\/][^>]*>)/g, "$1 />");  //remove \n and join opening with closing tags of the same node to one entire node if no content is between them
  result = result.replace(/(<([a-zA-Z:]+\b)[^>]*>)\n\s*([^<]+)\n\s*(<\/\2>)/g, "$1$3$4"); //remove \n between opening, content and closing tags of the same node (to display in one line)

  return result;
}
```

Version II - catch also opening and closing tags of the same node as one node (no needed additional fixes at the end):

```
function XMLTree( xmlString , indent )
{
  indent = indent || "\t"; //can be specified by second argument of the function

  var tabs = "";  //store the current indentation

  var result = xmlString.replace(
    /\s*<[^>\/]*>[^<>]*<\/[^>]*>|\s*<.+?>|\s*[^<]+/g , //pattern to match nodes (angled brackets or text)
    function(m,i)
    {
      m = m.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");  //trim the match just in case

      if(i<38)
       if (/^<[?]xml/.test(m))  return m+"\n";  //if the match is a header, ignore it

      if (/^<[/]/.test(m))  //if the match is a closing tag
       {
          tabs = tabs.replace(indent, "");  //remove one indent from the store
          m = tabs + m;  //add the tabs at the beginning of the match
       }
       else if (/<.*>.*<\/.*>|<.*[^>]\/>/.test(m))  //if the match contains an entire node
       {
        //leave the store as is or
        m = m.replace(/(<[^\/>]*)><[\/][^>]*>/g, "$1 />");  //join opening with closing tags of the same node to one entire node if no content is between them
        m = tabs + m; //add the tabs at the beginning of the match
       }
       else if (/<.*>/.test(m)) //if the match starts with an opening tag and does not contain an entire node
       {
        m = tabs + m;  //add the tabs at the beginning of the match
        tabs += indent;  //and add one indent to the store
       }
       else  //if the match contain a text node
       {
        m = tabs + m;  // add the tabs at the beginning of the match
       }

      //return m+"\n";
      return "\n"+m; //content has additional space(match) from header
    }//anonymous function
  );//replace

  return result;
}
```